# How can I prove this equivalent condition for weak convergence for random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

**My problem:**

I would like to prove that if $X_n$ and $X$ are real valued random variable then $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} X$ if and only if for all $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ (where $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ denotes all the functions $C^{\infty}$ with compact support) holds $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

**My attempt:**

I know that holds a similar statement where the $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ are replaced by Lipschitz and bounded function but I have no idea for the problem above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove the converse but first, for continuous functions with compact support.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function, define $p:=\sup_x |f(x)|,$ and for all $k \in \mathbb{N},\theta_k(x)=\min(1,\max(0,k+1-|x|)),x \in \mathbb{R}.$

So $$|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq E[|f(X_n)|(1-\theta_k(X_n))]+|E[f(X_n)\theta_k(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|\leq p(1-E[\theta_k(X_n)])+|E[f(X_n)\theta_k(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|$$

So
$$\limsup_n|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq p(1-E[\theta_k(X)])+|E[f(X) \theta_k(X)] -E[f(X)]|$$
by assumption, since $\theta_k, f\theta_k$ are continuous with compact support.

Then using dominated convergence theorem, we have $\lim_kE[\theta_k(X)]=1,$ and $\lim_kE[f(X)\theta_k]=E[f(X)].$
Which means that $\lim_nE[f(X_n)]=E[f(X)],$ for all bounded and continuous functions $f.$

Concerning your problem since $C_c \subset \overline{C_c^{\infty}}$ (for $||.||_{\infty}$,) so take $f \in C_c,\epsilon>0,$ $\exists \phi$ such that $||f-\phi||_{\infty} \leq \epsilon/2$

So $$|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq \epsilon/2+|E[\phi(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|$$
Finally $$\limsup_n |E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq \epsilon,$$ for all continuous functions $f$ with compact support.

(The result is also true for any $\mathcal{Q} \subset C_b$ such that $C_c \subset \overline{\mathcal{Q}},$ for the norm $||.||_{\infty}$)

Comment: Maybe in the last part you meant $|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq |E[f(X_n)]-E[\phi(X_n)]|+|E[\phi(X_n)]-E[\phi(X)]|+|E[\phi(X)]-E[f(X)]|$ ?

Comment: We can say that also